# Ubuntu 22.04 wifi disabled

Tags: 22.04, iwlwifi

I've just installed an Ubuntu 22.04 on my Dell Latitude 5480 but the wifi card doesn't work. The `ifconfig` command doesn't show the wlp2s0 device. It looks like it's a hardware problem:

Results of `sudo lshw -C network` :

```
*-network DISABLED  
       description: Wireless interface  
       product: Wireless 8265 / 8275  
       vendor: Intel Corporation  
       physical id: 0  
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0  
       logical name: wlp2s0  
       version: 78  
       seria,l: 5c:5f:67:c8:6b:3a  
       width: 64 bits  
       clock: 33MHz  
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless   
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.15.0-60-generic   firmware=36.ca7b901d.0 8265-36.ucode
latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11  
       resources: irq:130 memory:ef000000-ef001fff   *-network  
       description: Ethernet interface  
       product: Ethernet Connection (4) I219-LM  
       vendor: Intel Corporation  
       physical id: 1f.6  
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6  
       logical name: enp0s31f6  
       version: 21  
       serial: 10:65:30:2d:30:03  
       size: 1Gbit/s  
       capacity: 1Gbit/s  
       width: 32 bits  
       clock: 33MHz  
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation   
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=5.15.0-60-generic duplex=full firmware=0.1-4
ip=192.168.1.12 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair
speed=1Gbit/s  
       resources: irq:126 memory:ef200000-ef21ffff
```

Results of `sudo dmesg | grep iwl` :

```
    [    6.846782] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
    [    6.863786] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 36.ca7b901d.0 8265-36.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
    [    6.990169] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 8265, REV=0x230
    [    7.095504] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: base HW address: 5c:5f:67:c8:6b:3a
    [    7.172191] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
    [    7.528594] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0
    [   16.746235] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: RF_KILL bit toggled to disable radio.
    [   16.746248] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: reporting RF_KILL (radio disabled)
    [   17.167768] WARNING: CPU: 1 PID: 50 at drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/pcie/trans.c:2054 __iwl_trans_pcie_grab_nic_access.part.0+0x200/0x240 [iwlwifi]
    [   17.167793] Modules linked in: cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg bnep nls_iso8859_1 mei_hdcp snd_soc_skl intel_rapl_msr snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_sst_ipc snd_soc_sst_dsp snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_soc_acpi_intel_match dell_rbtn snd_soc_acpi snd_ctl_led snd_soc_core snd_compress snd_hda_codec_realtek ac97_bus snd_hda_codec_generic dell_laptop snd_pcm_dmaengine intel_tcc_cooling dell_smm_hwmon x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg coretemp snd_intel_sdw_acpi uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc snd_hda_codec videobuf2_memops kvm_intel dell_wmi iwlmvm kvm snd_hda_core mac80211 ledtrig_audio dell_smbios snd_hwdep input_leds videobuf2_v4l2 rapl dcdbas libarc4 snd_pcm videobuf2_common videodev wmi_bmof intel_wmi_thunderbolt serio_raw dell_wmi_descriptor intel_cstate btusb mc snd_timer lis3lv02d_i2c iwlwifi ee1004 snd lis3lv02d btrtl btbcm cfg80211 btintel soundcore bluetooth ecdh_generic ecc processor_thermal_device_pci_legacy processor_thermal_device
    [   17.167952] RIP: 0010:__iwl_trans_pcie_grab_nic_access.part.0+0x200/0x240 [iwlwifi]
    [   17.167991]  iwl_trans_pcie_grab_nic_access+0x45/0x80 [iwlwifi]
    [   17.168007]  iwl_write_prph_delay+0x27/0x80 [iwlwifi]
    [   17.168021]  iwl_fw_dbg_stop_restart_recording.part.0+0x11e/0x280 [iwlwifi]
    [   17.168043]  iwl_fw_dbg_stop_sync+0x46/0x50 [iwlwifi]
    [   17.168060]  iwl_mvm_stop_device+0x3b/0x80 [iwlmvm]
    [   17.168077]  __iwl_mvm_mac_stop+0x69/0x170 [iwlmvm]
    [   17.168090]  iwl_mvm_mac_stop+0x77/0xa0 [iwlmvm]
    [   17.168366] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: iwlwifi transaction failed, dumping registers
    [   17.168990] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: iwlwifi device config registers:
    [   17.170561] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 00000000: 24fd8086 00100406 02800078 00000000 ef000004 00000000 00000000 00000000
    [   17.171175] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 00000020: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00508086 00000000 000000c8 00000000 000001ff
    [   17.171796] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 00000040: 00020010 10008ec0 00190c10 0045e811 10110142 00000000 00000000 00000000
    [   17.172449] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 00000060: 00000000 00080812 00000405 00000000 00010001 00000000 00000000 00000000
    [   17.173088] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 00000080: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
    [   17.173741] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 000000a0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
    [   17.174394] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 000000c0: 00000000 00000000 c823d001 0d000000 00814005 fee00378 00000000 00000000
    [   17.174998] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 000000e0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
    [   17.175623] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 00000100: 14010001 00000000 00000000 00462031 00000000 00002000 00000000 00000000
    [   17.176209] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 00000120: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
    [   17.176823] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 00000140: 14c10003 ffc86b3a 5c5f67ff 15410018 10031003 0001001e 00481e1f 6002000f
    [   17.177405] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: iwlwifi device memory mapped registers:
    [   17.178561] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 00000000: 00480000 00000000 00000000 00000080 00000000 00000000 00000010 00000000
    [   17.179193] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 00000020: 00000011 00000008 00000230 d55555d5 d55555d5 d55555d5 80008040 001f0042
    [   17.180066] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: iwlwifi device AER capability structure:
    [   17.180962] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 00000000: 14010001 00000000 00000000 00462031 00000000 00002000 00000000 00000000
    [   17.181634] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 00000020: 00000000 00000000 00000000
    [   17.182282] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: iwlwifi parent port (0000:00:1c.2) config registers:
    [   17.183077] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.2: 00000000: 9d128086 00100407 060400f1 00810000 00000000 00000000 00020200 200000f0
    [   17.183788] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.2: 00000020: ef00ef00 0001fff1 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000040 00000000 001203ff
    [   17.184471] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.2: 00000040: 01428010 00008001 0010000f 03724c13 70110042 0034b200 01480000 00000008
    [   17.185163] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.2: 00000060: 00000000 00000837 00000400 0000000e 00010003 00000000 00000000 00000000
    [   17.185899] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.2: 00000080: 00019005 fee00278 00000000 00000000 0000a00d 07a71028 00000000 00000000
    [   17.186637] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.2: 000000a0: c8030001 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
    [   17.187371] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.2: 000000c0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 07001001 00001842 099e0008 00000000
    [   17.188066] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.2: 000000e0: 00630300 00000000 00100016 00000000 00000150 4c000000 08400fb3 03000004
    [   17.188796] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.2: 00000100: 14010001 00000000 00010000 00060011 00000000 00002000 00000000 00000000
    [   17.189498] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.2: 00000120: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000007 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
    [   17.190204] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.2: 00000140: 2001000d 0000000f 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
    [   17.190953] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.2: 00000160: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
    [   17.191646] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.2: 00000180: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
    [   17.192349] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.2: 000001a0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
    [   17.193046] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.2: 000001c0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
    [   17.193782] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.2: 000001e0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
    [   17.194482] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.2: 00000200: 2201001e 00b0281f 6002280f
    [   17.195170] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: iwlwifi root port (0000:00:1c.2) AER cap structure:
    [   17.195847] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.2: 00000000: 14010001 00000000 00010000 00060011 00000000 00002000 00000000 00000000
    [   17.196533] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.2: 00000020: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000007 00000000 00000000
    [   17.596748] WARNING: CPU: 1 PID: 50 at drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/mvm/mac80211.c:1228 __iwl_mvm_mac_stop+0x11d/0x170 [iwlmvm]
    [   17.596770] Modules linked in: cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg bnep nls_iso8859_1 mei_hdcp snd_soc_skl intel_rapl_msr snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_sst_ipc snd_soc_sst_dsp snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_soc_acpi_intel_match dell_rbtn snd_soc_acpi snd_ctl_led snd_soc_core snd_compress snd_hda_codec_realtek ac97_bus snd_hda_codec_generic dell_laptop snd_pcm_dmaengine intel_tcc_cooling dell_smm_hwmon x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg coretemp snd_intel_sdw_acpi uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc snd_hda_codec videobuf2_memops kvm_intel dell_wmi iwlmvm kvm snd_hda_core mac80211 ledtrig_audio dell_smbios snd_hwdep input_leds videobuf2_v4l2 rapl dcdbas libarc4 snd_pcm videobuf2_common videodev wmi_bmof intel_wmi_thunderbolt serio_raw dell_wmi_descriptor intel_cstate btusb mc snd_timer lis3lv02d_i2c iwlwifi ee1004 snd lis3lv02d btrtl btbcm cfg80211 btintel soundcore bluetooth ecdh_generic ecc processor_thermal_device_pci_legacy processor_thermal_device
    [   17.596928] RIP: 0010:__iwl_mvm_mac_stop+0x11d/0x170 [iwlmvm]
    [   17.596962]  iwl_mvm_mac_stop+0x77/0xa0 [iwlmvm]


`rfkill list`

    1: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN
            Soft blocked: no
            Hard blocked: no
    2: dell-bluetooth: Bluetooth
            Soft blocked: yes
            Hard blocked: no
    3: phy0: Wireless LAN
            Soft blocked: no
            Hard blocked: yes

`uname -a`

    Linux mowgli 5.19.0.32-generic #33-22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon Jan 30 17:03:34 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

`sudo dmesg | grep firmware`

    [ 2.739203] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] Finished loading DMC firmware i915/skl_dmc_ver1_27.bin (v1.27)
    [ 6.432781] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 36.ca7b901d.0 8265-36.ucode op_mode iwlmvm

I have no idea how to activate the card. I tried with `rfkill`, but it didn't work and the Fn keys don't seem to work.
```

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/143006/discussion-on-question-by-duddy67-ubuntu-22-04-wifi-disabled); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After like 2 days trying to figure out where this wifi problem comes from I finally found the solution thanks to this [post](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-us/000137415/how-to-disable-wireless-when-connected-via-wired-connection-on-latitude-and-precision-mobile-workstations?lwp=rt).
It actually has nothing to do with the firmware the driver or whatever. The problem actually comes from a (stupid) power management option in the bios which disables wireless when connected via wired connection.
[See the Dell documentation](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-us/000137415/how-to-disable-wireless-when-connected-via-wired-connection-on-latitude-and-precision-mobile-workstations?lwp=rt)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I needed to modify the file `/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf`.

Made a change from:

```
wifi.powersave = 3
```

to:

```
wifi.powersave = 2
```

Comment: After a firmware update on 23rd Dec 2023 WiFi adaptor disappeared when connected to Ethernet. I checked the BIOS and there was no entry for WiFi so tried this. This worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

I've seen this on one of my laptops.  I recommend you perform a

1. sudo apt update
2. sudo apt upgrade

Then after  reboot see if it fixed the problem.

Comment: I've already done that but it didn't fix the problem. It turns out it's a bug in the linux kernel.
Does your laptop run with an Intel Wireless 8265 / 8275 card ? If it does how did you fix the problem ?

Comment: No, sorry it wasn't much help.  Not the same card.  Did Intel make Linux drivers for that card?  I stuck to wired connection for a few months then when a newer version of Ubuntu came out it included the required drivers.

Comment: Yes Intel did a linux driver for the Dual Band Wireless-AC 8265 https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/wireless.html 
But for whatever reason there is a bug in the kernel related to the firmware https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=215635